# Membership renewal forms - am I handling this correctly?

Tags: civimember, forms

I just wanted to clarify if what I'm doing is best practice.

When a user signs up as a member for the first time we ask the standard core info and payment information (we give the option of using GoCardless or Stripe) we also ask a few personal optional questions about the user.

It's an annual membership so one year on, when they renew, they are directed to another page which basically is basically a clone of the sign up page with core info, payment, but doesn't include the questions we asked the first time around.

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: V hard to answer this as we have no idea if it is useful to you or the member to be able to view and/or edit the answers to the 'questions we asked first time around'. If you don't want them seeing it then yes your approach sounds valid, especially if the renewal reminder that is going out to them is using a checksum and link to the renewal page.

Answer (score 1):

What i do is I have the same profile, but since they see the info filled in, they can just browse over that area. I have found it helpful as some people like to update info, such as, in our case, emergency contact, and volunteering preferences.